# Function taking an arbitrary number of arguments

Tags: function-construction, core-language

Is it posible to define a multivariate function where the number of indipendent variables is not fixed?

For simulation reasons I have to change the dimensionality (and also the definition) of my function making it to be:

$f(x_0,x_1, \ldots, x_k)$ where $k$ can change.

My function is:

$$f(x_0,x_1, \ldots, x_k)= \sum_{d=0}^{d=k} x_d\,d\,u(d)$$

Comment: Yes, it is, but it sounds like to want a *list* as input.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the possible solution Sumit offers, you can also define functions to take variable numbers of arguments directly:

```
f[xs___] := Dot[{xs},{xs}]
{f[1,2,3], f[1], f[]}
```

> {14, 1, 0}

Usually, I turn these into a list like this so that you can use functions like `Length` on them:

```
f[xsSeq___] := With[
  {xs = {xsSeq}},
  ...]
```

Here are a few pieces of relevant documentation:

- [Sequences](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Sequences.html) (tutorial)
- [Patterns](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Patterns.html)
- [Sequence](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sequence.html)

Answer (score 3):

with `a[n]` being a predefined function

```
f[x_List] := Module[{n}, n = Length[x];
             Sum[1/i a[i] x[[i]], {i, n}]]

f[{x1, x2, x3}]
```

> x1 a[1] + 1/2 x2 a[2] + 1/3 x3 a[3]

```
f[{q1, q2, q3, q4}]
```

> q1 a[1] + 1/2 q2 a[2] + 1/3 q3 a[3] + 1/4 q4 a[4]